# How can I redirect to another path in JavaScript if a user inputs a non-numeric value for a paginated URL parameter?

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, pagination, routeparams

How to determine the type of a character wrapped in quotes?

I am retrieving params from a URL that needs to be evaluated through a type test to be used in a pagination service:
 `http://192.168.1.8:4200/posts?page=g`

I want to *redirect to another path if user puts anything other than number as a page param*

I have tried using `if(typeof JSON.parse(queries.page)===number)`

*it works in case of a number input*, but does not get through in case of a string for example:

`http://192.168.1.8:4200/posts?page=g`

it generates an error of:

VM873:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'g', "g" is not valid JSON
at JSON.parse ()
at :1:14

Comment: I think you can use Number(value) for example if you use Number("g") it will throw you a NaN but if you pass Number("2") it would say number

Comment: already tried that, in both cases it passes the test:
`typeof(Number('g'))
'number'`
`typeof(Number('1'))
'number'`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is using isNaN as an identifier:

I can use `isNaN()` instead of `typeof()`

`if(isNaN(+queries.page))`

returns `true`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN